# conditionally replace python dictionary value with comprehension

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, list-comprehension, nonetype

I am reading in a csv via `csv.DictReader` and trying to replace any empty values with the `None` value. `DictReader` seems to take the file as an instance of dictionaries where each row of the CSV is a dictionary (which I am fine with). However when I try to iterate through it row/dictionary by row/dictionary and replace any empty values (`""`) with `None` I seem to get unstuck. I had previously written this as a list comprehension like this:

```
    for row in data:
        row = [None if not x else x for x in row]
```

But I need to switch to using dictionaries rather than lists. I've not had any experience with dictionary comprehensions before but when I try to extend this for dictionaries I just cant get it to work. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
    for row in data:
        row.values() = [None if not x else x for x in row.values()}
```

but I just get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`. I've tried a lot of other things (too many to list here) like:

```
    for row in data:
        row = {k:None for k,v in row if v not v else v}
```

but this seems to have the same problem.

For reference, my data looks like:

```
    {'colour': 'ab6612', 'line': '1', 'name': 'Baker', 'stripe': ''}
    {'colour': 'f7dc00', 'line': '3', 'name': '', 'stripe': 'FFFFFF'}
```

and would ideally end up as:

```
    {'colour': 'ab6612', 'line': '1', 'name': 'Baker', 'stripe': None}
    {'colour': 'f7dc00', 'line': '3', 'name': None, 'stripe': 'FFFFFF'}
```

Comment: thanks all, {k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.items()} was just what I was looking for. I didn't realise I could nest the (v if v else None) like that. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you are changing the name `row` to reference a new dictionary in the for loop, this will not change anything inside your original list/DictReader object - `data` .

If data is a list, you should enumerate over `data` and change the dictionary inside data (or make that reference a new dictionary)

Example -

```
for i,row in enumerate(data):
     data[i] = {k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.items()}
```

Example test -

```
>>> data = [{1:2 , 3:''},{4:'',5:6}]
>>> for i,row in enumerate(data):
...     data[i] = {k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.items()}
...
>>> data
[{1: 2, 3: None}, {4: None, 5: 6}]
```

And since you are using DictReader class, you cannot directly, change the DictReader object, so you should create a new list , and add the changed row in the new list (or a DictWriter object, would prefer the DictWriter object) -

Example -

```
>>> newdata = []
>>> for row in data:
...     newdata.append({k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.items()})
```

Comment: `newdata = [{k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.items()} for row in data]` ?

Comment: Yea that would also do.

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is that you are trying to iterate twice over your dictionary whereas you only need to do it once.

Try:

```
data = {k:(v if v else None) for k,v in data.items()}
```

without the for-loop.

Comment: data is a list-like, not a dictionary, row is the dict.

Comment: You’re bloody right, should have read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSV and the data is too large please use iteritems()

> this will save prevent the large list generation caused by items()
>   Try:

```
new_data=[]    
for row in data:
    new_data.append({k:(v if v else None) for k,v in row.iteritems()})
```

> if you dont understand comprehensions follow this simple for loop:

```
for row in data:
    for k,v in row.iteritems():
        if not v:
            row[k]=None
```

> the second method is easy to understand also does not create an additional list which is a better for higher performance